# MySQL Query - SELECT (average of a category) AS "CATEGORY AVERAGE"

Tags: sql, mysql, aggregate-functions

**Objective:** When user browses to a particular seller, then display his average along with the average of sellers from similar category for easy comparison.

**Example Data:**

```
Seller | Category |  Qty |  Sales  
--------------------------------------------  
Harry  | Mango    | 100  |  50000  
John   | Apple    | 75   |  50500  
Max    | Mango    | 44   |  20000  
Ash    | Mango    | 60   |  35000  
Lingo  | Apple    | 88   |  60000
```

**Required Output:** *(When user browses to Ash)*
Quantity Sold by Ash: **60**
Average quantity sold by other Mango sellers: **68** *(Avg of 100, 44 & 60)*

Average Price of Ash: **583.33** *(35000 / 60)*
Average Price of Other Mango Sellers: **514.70** *(Weighted Average of Prices)*

**Skeleton Code:**

> SELECT 'Qty' AS 'Qty',
>   (SOME CODE) AS 'Avg Qty',
>   ('Sales' / 'Qty') AS 'Price',
>   (SOME CODE) AS 'Avg Price'
>   FROM 'SALES TABLE'
>   WHERE 'Seller' = 'Ash'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT yt.qty,
       x.cat_avg,
       yt.sales/yt.qty AS avg_price,
       NULL AS weighted_average 
  FROM YOUR_TABLE yt
  JOIN (SELECT t.category,
               AVG(t.qty) AS cat_avg
          FROM YOUR_TABLE t
      GROUP BY t.category) x ON x.category = yt.category
 WHERE yt.seller = 'Ash'
```

I'll fill in the weighted average when you supply the equation, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    sellers.Qty,
    ROUND(AVG(s.Qty), 0) AS TotalQty,
    ROUND(( sellers.Sales / sellers.Qty ), 2) AS AvgPrice,
    ROUND(( AVG(s.Sales) / AVG(s.Qty) ),2) AS TotalAvgPrice
FROM
    sellers 
LEFT JOIN sellers AS s On sellers.Category = s.Category
WHERE
    sellers.Seller = "Ash"
```